# Gnumake in crontab

Tags: makefile, cron

I am trying to run a make file from within cron. My command is pretty simple:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/make -C "/home/path_to_file/" -f "/home/path_to_file/Makefile"
```

It runs normally in the shell, but it fails in the crontab.

- How can I debug this kind of problem?
- Any suggestions what might be my error?

Comment: No need to put `-f "/home/path_to_file/Makefile"` unless the Makefile is in a different directory... `-C` effectively does a `cd` before running `make` like normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It likely fails because `PATH` is not set. You should set the PATH in the `Makefile` and export it:

```
  PATH := /usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/some/other/dir
  export PATH
```

You can test your command by specifying a very limited environment:

```
/usr/bin/env -i PATH=directorylist_here HOME=$HOME your_cron_cmd
```

PS: Usually any output on stdout and stderr is mailed to you by cron. Did you check your inbox for cron mails? These may provide additional clues.
The mails are sent to the mailbox of the user the crontab belongs to. So if this is run as root it will be in root's inbox. (Of course this will work only if stdin+stdout weren't redirected to `/dev/null`). On a Unix system, you can read the inbox mails with the `mail` or maybe `mailx` commands.

Comment: Só directory list should have the directory in which the makefile is? Should I include other directories as well?

Comment: And how to check cron mails?

Comment: @lf_araujo See modified answer.